# Sobre Deferred e Promises JQuery

Tags: jquery

Preciso de ajuda para entender este conceito de Deferred e Promises no JQuery, parece que há uma biblioteca para promises(há mesmo?) mas o JQuery tá quebrando o galho com a implementação disso desde a versão 1.5.

Me ajude a entender aplicado no exemplo abaixo:

```
 var
 log = function (msg) {
     $('#output').text($('#output').text() + ' ' + msg);
 },


 printDone = function (obj) {
     log(obj + ' done ..');
 },


 timer1 = $.Deferred(
     function (def) {
     setTimeout(function () {
         def.resolve("timer 1");
     }, 2000);
 }).promise(),


     timer2 = $.Deferred(function (def) {
         setTimeout(function () {
             def.resolve("timer 2");
         }, 4000);
     }).promise();
 timer1.done(function (data) {
     printDone(data)
 });
 timer2.done(function (data) {
     printDone(data)
 });
 $.when(timer1, timer2).done(function () {
     printDone('timer 1 and 2')
 })
```

Me ajudem a entender essa  ai, se possível comentar o código ou explicar, como achar melhor!
Eu já dei uma lida, mas preciso de um refresh para eu entender melhor..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
timer1 = $.Deferred(...)
```

Isso cria um *deferred* ("deferido", "adiado"). Esse objeto inicia no estado "pendente". Somente quando *alguém* chamar o método `resolve` ou `resolveWith` ele passara ao estado "resolvido". O que isso significa?

- Se alguém chamar o método `timer1.done(função)` enquanto seu estado estiver "pendente", essa função será enfileirada para ser chamada mais tarde;
- Quando esse objeto passar do estado "pendente" para o "resolvido", todas as funções enfileiradas serão chamadas, na ordem;
- Se alguém chamar o método `timer1.done(função)` enquanto seu estado estiver "resolvido", essa função será chamada imediatamente.

No caso, o `timer1` foi [transformado em uma promessa e] usado diretamente - com o `done` - e indiretamente, com o `when`. Como ele ainda está no estado "pendente", isso significa que ambas as funções serão enfileiradas pra mais tarde, e a do `done` será chamada antes da do `when`.

```
timer1 = $.Deferred(function (def) { ... }).promise();
```

Isso cria o *deferred* e imediatamente chama uma função que o utiliza, numa única expressão. Apenas isso. Essa chamada acima seria o equivalente a:

```
timer1 = $.Deferred();
(function(def) { ... }).call(timer1, timer1); // Tanto o this quanto o 1º argumento
                                              // são o próprio Deferred
timer1 = timer1.promise();
```

Mas o estado do `Deferred` continua "pendente", a chamada da função extra não muda [necessariamente] isso. E de fato:

```
function (def) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        def.resolve("timer 1");
    }, 2000);
}
```

pode-se ver que essa função não faz nada imediatamente - ela dispara uma nova função a ser executada dali a 2 segundos (via `setTimeout`), e retorna. O estado do *deferred* continua o mesmo.

## 2 segundos depois...

```
def.resolve("timer 1");
```

Isso muda o estado do `timer1` para "resolvido". No caso, `"timer 1"` é apenas um argumento, poderia-se usar outra coisa, ou coisas, ou nada. O(s) argumentos(s) usado(s) no `resolve` passa(m) direto para os *callbacks*.

Como foi dito, mudar o estado de um *deferred* de "pendente" para "resolvido" desenfileira as funções associadas a ele e as executa. A primeira delas é a função:

```
timer1.done(function (data) {
    printDone(data)
});
```

Que - como não depende de mais ninguém - executa imediatamente. Você deve ver um `"timer 1"` sendo impresso na saída.

A segunda delas foi criada através do `$.when`, de modo que só será executada quando **todas** as suas dependências estiverem resolvidas. `timer1` está resolvido, mas `timer2` ainda está pendente, de modo que essa função ainda não executa.

## mais 2 segundos depois...

Após mais 2 segundos (4 no total, conforme o `setTimeout` da função usada com `timer2`), o seguinte código é executado:

```
def.resolve("timer 2");
```

Isso resolve o `timer2`, desenfileirando seus *callbacks* e os executando, tal como ocorreu com o `timer1`. Você deverá ver `"timer 2"` impresso na saída, já que o código do `done` foi o primeiro a ser enfileirado.

Agora que tanto `timer1` quanto `timer2` estão no estado "resolvido", então o código do `when` está livre para executar:

```
$.when(timer1, timer2).done(function () {
    printDone('timer 1 and 2')
})
```

Você verá então `"timer 1 and 2"` impresso na saída. Note que isso ocorre **antes** que o `def.resolve("timer 2")` retorne - pois foi essa chamada que "disparou" os *callbacks* ainda pendentes de `timer2`. Isso ficará claro se você inserir essas duas checagens na criação dos *timers*:

```js
// Modifiquei o log pra ficar mais fácil a visualização
var log = function (msg) {
     $('#output').append('<li>' + msg + '</li>');
 },


 printDone = function (obj) {
     log(obj + ' done ..');
 },


 timer1 = $.Deferred(
     function (def) {
     setTimeout(function () {
         log("Vai resolver o timer 1");
         def.resolve("timer 1");
         log("Resolveu o timer 1");
     }, 2000);
 }).promise(),


     timer2 = $.Deferred(function (def) {
         setTimeout(function () {
             log("Vai resolver o timer 2");
             def.resolve("timer 2");
             log("Resolveu o timer 2");
         }, 4000);
     }).promise();
 timer1.done(function (data) {
     printDone(data)
 });
 timer2.done(function (data) {
     printDone(data)
 });
 $.when(timer1, timer2).done(function () {
     printDone('timer 1 and 2')
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

Comment: se eu tivesse uma função chama CallAjax, e nela tive-se uma requisição AJAX, eu poderia fazer : `$.when(CallAjax).done(function(){});` para eu realizar alguma função após a requisição, considerando que as operações assíncronas(fade,ajax) já possuem promises?

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Sim, inclusive essa é a maneira mais recomendada de se fazer isso em códigos novos (só não sei se o `when` é necessário, acho que dá pra fazer simplesmente `CallAjax.done(fn)`). Há também algumas funções que *não* retornam um promise diretamente, mas que permitem requisitar um, ex.: `$(elemento).hide(2000).promise()` (retorna um objeto jQuery comum, mas ao pedir o promise ele te dá um que só vai resolver ao final da animação de esconder)

Comment: Perfeito @mgibsonbr, tá ficando cada vez mais claro, to apanhando pra aprende isso porquê to confundindo deferred com promise, e ainda existe o `deferred.promise()`, mas to me resolvendo aos poucos, espero ficar 100% interado disso, valeu até agora, um grande abraço pra você fera!